# Getting Syntax error in nested SQL query in sqlalchemy

Tags: python, sql, sqlite, sqlalchemy, syntax-error

I have made a table 'temporary'(x,train1,train2,..train4) with 5 columns.I want to fill the column 'train1' with  calculated data (train.y1-ideal.y1) from tables 'train'(x,y1) and 'ideal'(x,y1). But the following nested sql query is giving '**syntax error near SELECT'**. What is wrong with it?

```
train=1
with engine.connect() as conn:
  while train<2:
    ideal=1
    col_train='y'+str(train)
    train_no=str(train)
    col_ideal='y'+str(ideal)
    query1=conn.execute(text(("INSERT INTO temporary (train%s) VALUES (SELECT (train.%s-ideal.%s)*(train.%s-ideal.%s) FROM train INNER JOIN ideal ON train.x=ideal.x)")%(train_no,col_train,col_ideal,col_train,col_ideal)))
    train+=1
```

Answer (score 0):

> **What is wrong with it?**

I believe that your issue is that the `SELECT ....` should be enclosed in parenthesises.

**The Fix** *(assuming that I've correctly added the parenthesises in the right place, if not see the demo below)*

```
query1=conn.execute(text(("INSERT INTO temporary (train%s) VALUES ((SELECT (train.%s-ideal.%s)*(train.%s-ideal.%s) FROM train INNER JOIN ideal ON train.x=ideal.x))")%(train_no,col_train,col_ideal,col_train,col_ideal)))
```

The following is a demo of the working SQL (albeit that the tables may be different) :-

```
DROP TABLE IF EXISTS train;
DROP TABLE IF EXISTS ideal;
DROP TABLE IF EXISTS temporary;
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS train (x INTEGER PRIMARY KEY, train_no INTEGER,col_train TEXT);
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS ideal (x INTEGER PRIMARY KEY, col_ideal INTEGER, col_train INTEGER);
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS temporary (train_no INTEGER);
INSERT INTO temporary (train_no) VALUES (
    ( /*<<<<<<<<<< ADDED */
        SELECT (train.col_train-ideal.col_ideal)*(train.col_train-ideal.col_ideal) 
        FROM train INNER JOIN ideal ON train.x=ideal.x
    ) /*<<<<<<<<<< ADDED */
);
```

When executed then:-

```
INSERT INTO temporary (train_no) VALUES (
    ( /* ADDED */
        SELECT (train.col_train-ideal.col_ideal)*(train.col_train-ideal.col_ideal) 
        FROM train INNER JOIN ideal ON train.x=ideal.x
    ) /* ADDED */
)
> Affected rows: 1
> Time: 0.084s
```

As opposed to (without the parenthesises) :-

```
INSERT INTO temporary (train_no) VALUES (
    /*(*/ /* ADDED */
        SELECT (train.col_train-ideal.col_ideal)*(train.col_train-ideal.col_ideal) 
        FROM train INNER JOIN ideal ON train.x=ideal.x
    /*)*/ /* ADDED */
)
> near "SELECT": syntax error
> Time: 0s
```